# Angular 6 - Updating ng-dirty when a value in an input is reverted back to it's original state

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an angular form where a save button is only enabled if a value is changed within a form. However, is it possible to detect if the value is returned to it's original state?

For example: If, onload, one inputs value is "Title One". If the user then changes "one" to "two", the form is then dirty and enables the save button which is great. However, if the user presses `Control + Z`, or retypes "Title One", is there a way to make the form pristine and therefore disable the save button (as the original value has been returned)

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

 <input type="text" placeholder="Title" formControlName="title">


 <button (click)="saveData()" [disabled]="!myForm.dirty">
  Save
 </button>

</form>
```

Comment: surely you just want to disable the save button when the form is invalid?

Comment: I have a host listener implemented to do determine whether the user tries refreshing the page, or leaving the tab. If the form is dirty, it'll alert the user so they can decide whether to leave the page or stay. However, if the above scenario plays out where the user modifies a field and then reverts it back, the form still remains dirty.

Comment: You can do this, perhaps using ngrx if it's a common requirement in your application, as it's more to do with state management. 

Alternatively, you can add compare the new state of the form control to a hard-coded initial state, which can be stored as an object.

Comment: Interesting idea. Thanks! Do you have an example of how that might be achieved at all please?

Comment: Sure, I had a busy day yesterday. I will answer later today.